Am running into a stack overflow error with OpenWindow on C# using SpashKit
The error I am getting:

Exception has occurred: CLR/System.StackOverflowException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in SplashKitSDK.dll

My code: (Most is // to find my issue)

// Give us access to methods in SplashKit library
using static SplashKitSDK.SplashKit;

// Give us access to convert methods from C#
using static System.Convert;
string userInput;
int width, height, delaySeconds;
// Output a message
WriteLine("Window Test");
// Write("How wide do you want the window? Enter width: ");
// userInput = ReadLine();
// // Call ToInt32 from Convert
// width = ToInt32(userInput);
// Write("How high do you want the window? Enter height: ");
// userInput = ReadLine();
// // Call ToInt32 from Convert
// height = ToInt32(userInput);
// Write("How many seconds do you want it to show for? Enter seconds: ");
// userInput = ReadLine();
// delaySeconds = ToInt32(userInput);
// Call open window from SplashKit
OpenWindow("Test Window", 600, 600);
// ClearScreen(RandomColor());
// RefreshScreen();
// Delay(delaySeconds * 1000);
// CloseAllWindows();
I have tried everything I can think of, altho I am new to c#.

Please format your code properly. Also please remove the lines that are not a part of a [mre].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
